# Change jQuery code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progressive-web-apps

I have `jquery` function to control page menu elements with dynamic screen size. But this code requires `jquery` lib's. But this effecting my loading performance.
I can't use `async` loading  attribute for `jquery` because  this function requires this library. But if I could change to pure `JavaScript` then loading performance will be high. (Progressive Web Apps)
But when I really struggling with this conversions. Anyone knows how to convert to pure `JavaScript`?

```
function calcWidth() {
  var navwidth = 0;
  var morewidth = $('#main .more').outerWidth(true);
  $('#main > li:not(.more)').each(function() {
      navwidth += $(this).outerWidth( true );
  });
  var availablespace = $('nav').outerWidth(true) - morewidth;

  if (navwidth > availablespace) {
    var lastItem = $('#main > li:not(.more)').last();
    lastItem.attr('data-width', lastItem.outerWidth(true));
    lastItem.prependTo($('#main .more ul'));
    calcWidth();
  } else {
    var firstMoreElement = $('#main li.more li').first();
    if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.data('width') < availablespace) {
      firstMoreElement.insertBefore($('#main .more'));
    }
  }

  if ($('.more li').length > 0) {
    $('.more').css('display','inline-block');
  } else {
    $('.more').css('display','none');
  }
}
$(window).on('resize load',function(){
  calcWidth();
});
```

Comment: Break it up into small pieces. Do research. Remember, we're not here to translate your code for you.

Comment: Any selectors not just id selectors you can start looking at [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)  then loop through the matches in a standard loop instead of jQuery `each` for thing slike `prependTo` I would do a straight up google, `jQuery PrependTo in pure Javascript` or look at the actual jquery source code freely available.

Comment: Remember that jQuery make your code 'cross-browser compatible'. When you write pure JS code, you may have problems with old web-browsers compability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function calcWidth() {
  var navwidth = 0;
  var morewidth = document.querySelectorAll('#main .more')[0].width;
  document.querySelectorAll('#main > li:not(.more)').forEach(function(item,index) {
      navwidth += item.width;
  });
  var availablespace = document.querySelectorAll('nav')[0].width - morewidth;

  if (navwidth > availablespace) {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('#main > li:not(.more)');
    var lastItem = arr[arr.length-1];
    lastItem.setAttribute('data-width', lastItem.width);
    document.querySelectorAll('#main .more ul')[0].appendChild(lastItem);
    lastItem.parentNode.removeChild(lastItem);
    calcWidth();
  } else {
    var firstMoreElement = document.querySelectorAll('#main li.more li')[0];
    if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.width < availablespace) {
              firstMoreElement.parentnode.insertBefore(firstMoreElement,document.querySelectorAll('#main .more')[0]);
      firstMoreElement.parentNode.removeChild(firstMoreElement);
    }
  }

 if (document.querySelectorAll('.more li').length > 0) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.more').forEach(function(item,index){item.style.display='inline-block';});
} else {document.querySelectorAll('.more').forEach(function(item,index){item.style.display='none';});
}
}

window.onload=calcWidth;
window.onresize=calcWidth;
```

Answer if worked :)

Comment: Looks OK but when you change screen size (width) then menu elements still available (should be hidden)

Comment: I've changed it. Try one more time, pls

Comment: Still same, not stacking into drop down menu

Comment: I've changed it one more time. Will you try it?

Comment: No. Not stacking

Comment: What does it write in the console?

Comment: Can you please send all HTML and full description of what should it do so I can try it on my computer?

Comment: i have `JS` error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelectorAll is not defined
    at calcWidth`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at calcWidth`

Comment: On which of the lines?

Comment: Will be line 18

Comment: Are you sure this ('#main li.more li') selector is correct?

Comment: `jQuery` code in my post is working if all elements does not with into screen then all buttons are stacked one my one into drop down menu.

Comment: which elements should the selector choose?

Comment: There are no elements selected with selector ('#main li.more li'), because are no <li>s in <li class="more hidden" data-width="80"> There is one <i> element, did you mean that one?

Comment: i's just pictures for each button. That is fine

Comment: I don't understand. How can selector ('#main li.more li') choose anything if there is nothing that is suitable?